# How to remove unecessary level of array of object in a recursive function (PHP)

Tags: php, recursion, logic

I'm working in a function to prepare an api json response, the content of this json is generated by a cms and it's initial structure is pretty close to this provided here.

I was having a good progress until this funcion. Now I'm trying to access recursively, each ['children'] element of the array, but I need to remove all ['children'] with ["title"] = "Component drop zone", from my array, removing that children level and building a array where this child remove receive the next child.

Let me show my code:

```
function removePropertiesAndEmptyChildren(&$data) {
    
    foreach ($data as &$item) {
      $remove_keys = [
        'uid',
        'type',
        'enabled',
        'category',
        'status',
        'componentType',
        'selected',
        'isContainer',
        'mimicParent',
        'dropzoneId',
        'iconColor'
      ];
      foreach($remove_keys as $key) {
        if (isset($item[$key])) {
          unset($item[$key]);
        }
      }
      
      if (isset($item['children']) && empty($item['children'])) {
        unset($item['children']);
      }
      if(is_array($item)) {
        $this->removePropertiesAndEmptyChildren($item);
      }
    }
    return $data;
  }
```

This is my function and it is returning the follow array:

```
[
  {
    "title": "App Bar",
    "componentId": "cpt_***_app_bar",
    "uuid": "e985becb-7dc4-471c-937e-d06858b04a41",
    "parentUid": "root",
    "children": [
      {
        "parentUid": "cpt_***_app_bar",
        "title": "Component drop zone",
        "uuid": "d692d3b0-7434-4b45-93c1-6b9bf610065e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "List View",
    "componentId": "cpt_***_list_view",
    "uuid": "764be577-e1b7-4481-9ca7-0a22a74afa2d",
    "parentUid": "root",
    "children": [
      {
        "parentUid": "cpt_***_list_view",
        "title": "Component drop zone",
        "uuid": "92226f8a-913c-43a0-94e7-f79f77d28104",
        "children": [
          {
            "title": "Column",
            "componentId": "cpt_***_column",
            "uuid": "c15b5a8c-4a7f-4730-bc80-d0396db350f2",
            "parentUid": "component-drop-zone",
            "children": [
              {
                "parentUid": "cpt_***_column",
                "title": "Component drop zone",
                "uuid": "fd0c1a09-f0cb-4694-9f66-508de2ff5a51",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "title": "Hexa Link Button",
                    "componentId": "cpt_***_hexa_link_button",
                    "uuid": "97fe5f5b-8aee-4284-a536-b48c7121a80b",
                    "parentUid": "component-drop-zone"
                  },
                  {
                    "title": "Hexa Link Button",
                    "componentId": "cpt_***_hexa_link_button",
                    "uuid": "69354116-4b35-4f38-bae5-594714518587",
                    "parentUid": "component-drop-zone"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Pull To Refresh Action",
    "componentId": "cpt_***_pull_to_refresh_action",
    "uuid": "ac227b11-359c-41eb-8fc3-a7bad71995f1",
    "parentUid": "root"
  }
]
```

As a result I'm trying to reach the follow array:

```
[
  {
    "title": "App Bar",
    "componentId": "cpt_***_app_bar",
    "uuid": "e985becb-7dc4-471c-937e-d06858b04a41",
    "parentUid": "root"
  },
  {
    "title": "List View",
    "componentId": "cpt_***_list_view",
    "uuid": "764be577-e1b7-4481-9ca7-0a22a74afa2d",
    "parentUid": "root",
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "Column",
        "componentId": "cpt_***_column",
        "uuid": "c15b5a8c-4a7f-4730-bc80-d0396db350f2",
        "parentUid": "component-drop-zone",           
        "children": [
          {
            "title": "Hexa Link Button",
            "componentId": "cpt_***_hexa_link_button",
            "uuid": "97fe5f5b-8aee-4284-a536-b48c7121a80b",
            "parentUid": "component-drop-zone"
          },
          {
            "title": "Hexa Link Button",
            "componentId": "cpt_***_hexa_link_button",
            "uuid": "69354116-4b35-4f38-bae5-594714518587",
            "parentUid": "component-drop-zone"
          }
        ]           
        
      }
    ]   
  },
  {
    "title": "Pull To Refresh Action",
    "componentId": "cpt_***_pull_to_refresh_action",
    "uuid": "ac227b11-359c-41eb-8fc3-a7bad71995f1",
    "parentUid": "root"
  }
]
```

I have tried a lot of things, eg this foreach to try to remove the unecessary array level, but this isn't work:

```
$newData = [];
foreach ($array as $parent => $children) {
    foreach ($children as $child => $grandchildren) {
            $newData[$parent] = array_merge($newData[$parent] ?? [], $grandchildren);
        }
    }

    return $newData;
```

I'm really frustrated about that, I'm have low experience on Back End PHP. How can I reach the spected result?

Comment: To make it easier, create a new array with the data you want to keep instead of deleting in the same array you are iterating in.

Comment: What is a sample `&$data` input?